# php code to find city,state and country name using pincode

Tags: php

Is there any API or anything which provides city,state and country name when pincode is given.Please share if you have any solution

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you provide more context? What have you tried so far. Also, what do you mean by pincode?

Answer (score 2):

> Hello. there are many more sites which provides this kind of
>   information i will show you two of them.

1. [Third Party API](http://postalpincode.in/api/pincode/380026)
2. [Google API](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=380024)

try this url with your pincode. this will gives you data in json format like below one. i have removed some of data to show you so it was not exactly as per return response of third party api.

```
{
    "Message": "Number of Post office(s) found: 1",
    "Status": "Success",
    "PostOffice": [     
        {
            "Name": "I E Bapunagar",
            "Description": "",
            "BranchType": "Sub Post Office",
            "DeliveryStatus": "Delivery",
            "Taluk": "Ahmadabad City",
            "Circle": "Ahmadabad City",
            "District": "Ahmedabad",
            "Division": "Ahmedabad City",
            "Region": "Ahmedabad HQ",
            "State": "Gujarat",
            "Country": "India"
        }
    ]
}
```

> check it, and if you want any help,you can ask.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [GeoCoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

For example, to lookup zip 626134 use a request like this:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=626134&sensor=true

Comment: tanq it is even giving lat and long also